# Google Chrome extension that can take full-page, high-definition screenshot of a webpage

Tags: chrome, web, screenshot

I am looking for a Google Chrome extension that can take full-page, high-definition screenshot of a webpage.

I tried [Full Page Screen Capture](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/full-page-screen-capture/fdpohaocaechififmbbbbbknoalclacl?hl=en) but screenshot of a webpage aren't high-definition:

[image]

Same issue with [Nimbus](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nimbus-screenshot-screen/bpconcjcammlapcogcnnelfmaeghhagj):

[image]

Comment: @Robert thanks, clever trick, you're welcome to convert your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a plugin you can use a headless instance of chrome using your current user profile and let it render the page into a Chrome window of your size and then save it as PNG image using the following command-line

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"  --headless --disable-gpu --window-size=2000,5000 --user-data-dir="%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data" --virtual-time-budget=10000 --screenshot=chrome_screenshot.png https://stackoverflow.com/questions

When I execute this command the generated PNG image has a pretty good quality to me. And by the custom window size (which can be larger than your physical screen resolution) nothing has to be scrolled to make the screen-shot.